# Hybris Open External link in separated browser tab

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, jco

i need to open an external link, in separated tab, after a jco call in Hybris 1811.
i've created the button and the controller for the jco call, all works fine, but i can't open a new tab in the browser.

using java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url); i open a tab in server side,but i need obviouslly open the tab in client's browser.

Can anybody help me?

best regards
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to do this as below:

1. CMSLinkCOmponent: You can specify target as newWindow/sameWindow like below,

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSLinkComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;url;&linkRef;target(code)[default='sameWindow']
```

2. HTML:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google.com</a>
```